# Scrape some child links and then returning to the main scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a site with div elements and iteratively, for each div element I want to scrape some data from it and follow the child links it has and scrape more data from them.

Here is the code of quote.py

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotesItem


class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quote'
    baseurl='http://quotes.toscrape.com'
    start_urls = [baseurl]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_div_quotes=response.css('.quote')

        for quote in all_div_quotes:
            item=QuotesItem()

            title = quote.css('.text::text').extract()
            author = quote.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = quote.css('.tag::text').extract()
            author_details_url=self.baseurl+quote.css('.author+ a::attr(href)').extract_first()

            item['title']=title
            item['author']=author
            item['tags']=tags

            request = scrapy.Request(author_details_url,
                                     callback=self.author_born,
                                     meta={'item':item,'next_url':author_details_url})
            yield request

    def author_born(self, response):
        item=response.meta['item']
        next_url = response.meta['next_url']
        author_born = response.css('.author-born-date::text').extract()
        item['author_born']=author_born
        yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.author_birthplace,
                              meta={'item':item})

    def author_birthplace(self,response):
        item=response.meta['item']
        author_birthplace= response.css('.author-born-location::text').extract()
        item['author_birthplace']=author_birthplace
        yield item
```

Here is the code of items.py

```py
import scrapy

class QuotesItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
    author_born = scrapy.Field()
    author_birthplace = scrapy.Field()
```

I ran the command `scrapy crawl quote -o data.json`, but there was no error message and `data.json` was empty. I was expecting to get all the data in its corresponding field.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you see any scraped items in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your logs, you'll be able to find messages like this:

```
DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein>
```

Scrapy is automatically managing duplicates and trying not to visit one URL twice(for obvious reasons).
In you case you can add `dont_filter = True` to your requests and will see something like this:

```
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison/)
2019-07-15 19:33:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/> (referer: http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/)
```

Which is kinda strange indeed, because of page yields request to itself.

Overall you could end up with something like this:

```
import scrapy


class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quote'
    baseurl = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
    start_urls = [baseurl]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_div_quotes = response.css('.quote')

        for quote in all_div_quotes:
            item = dict()

            title = quote.css('.text::text').extract()
            author = quote.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = quote.css('.tag::text').extract()
            author_details_url = self.baseurl + quote.css('.author+ a::attr(href)').extract_first()

            item['title'] = title
            item['author'] = author
            item['tags'] = tags

            print(item)

            # Don't filter = True in case of we get two quotes of a single author.
            # This is not optimal though. Better decision will be to save author data to self.storage
            # And only visit new author info pages if needed, else take info from saved dict.

            request = scrapy.Request(author_details_url,
                                     callback=self.author_info,
                                     meta={'item': item},
                                     dont_filter=True)
            yield request

    def author_info(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        author_born = response.css('.author-born-date::text').extract()
        author_birthplace = response.css('.author-born-location::text').extract()
        item['author_born'] = author_born
        item['author_birthplace'] = author_birthplace
        yield item
```